Handling dynamic route data fetching and context in Next.js 13 with server components?
I'm working on a Next.js 14 app using the new app directory and server components. I have two main pages under the /email route:

/email - This page lists all emails.
/email/[id] - This page shows the email list on the left and the selected email's body on the right.

Problem I Encountered with Layout:
Initially, I wanted to use the layout for data fetching and pass the data through context to all child components. But I ran into these issues:

useParams isn't available in the layout, so I couldn't fetch data dynamically based on the URL parameter (id).
Layouts in Next.js 14 don't re-render on dynamic route changes, meaning the data remained static even when navigating between /email/1 and /email/2.
As a workaround, I had to pass default values like page=1 in the layout, but this caused issues when handling dynamic routes.

Current Solution:
I moved data fetching and the context (EmailProvider) from the layout to each page. Here’s what I’m doing now:

/email/page.tsx:


I fetch the list of emails based on the page query parameter using searchParams in a server component.
I use EmailProvider to store the emails in context, so it can be accessed in the EmailList component.
Here’s how I fetch the emails in /email/page.tsx:

// app/email/page.tsx (server-side component)

import { EmailProvider } from "@/context/EmailContext";
import EmailList from "@/components/Email/EmailList";

const EmailPage = async ({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) => {
  const page = searchParams?.page || "1"; // Get the current page from query params

  const fetchEmails = async (page: string) => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://example.com/email?page=${page}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data.list;
  };

  const emails = await fetchEmails(page); // Fetch all emails based on the page number

  return (
    <EmailProvider initialEmails={emails}>
      <EmailList /> {/* Renders the list of emails */}
    </EmailProvider>
  );
};

export default EmailPage;


/email/[id]/page.tsx:


This page fetches the body of a specific email based on the id and displays the EmailList and EmailBody side by side.
Here’s how I fetch the email body:

// app/email/[id]/page.tsx (server-side component)

import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

import EmailBody from "@/components/Email/EmailBody";
import EmailList from "@/components/Email/EmailList";
import { EmailProvider } from "@/context/EmailContext";

interface EmailPageProps {
  params: { id: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}

const EmailIDPage = async ({ params, searchParams }: EmailPageProps) => {
  const { id } = params;

  // Fetch the email list and the selected email in parallel
  const [listRes, emailRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`https://example.com/api/emails?page=${searchParams.page || '1'}`, {
      cache: "no-store",
    }),
    fetch(`https://example.com/api/emails/${id}`, {
      cache: "no-store",
    }),
  ]);

  if (!listRes.ok || !emailRes.ok) {
    notFound();
  }

  const emails = await listRes.json();
  const emailBodyData = await emailRes.json();

  // Find the selected email in the list to get the missing fields
  const selectedEmail = emails.list.find(
    (email: { id: string }) => email.id === id
  );

  if (!selectedEmail) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <EmailProvider initialEmails={emails}>
      <div className="min-h-screen">
        <div className="w-1/3">
          <EmailList activeId={id} />
        </div>

        <div className="w-2/3">
          <EmailBody email={{ ...selectedEmail, body: emailBodyData.body }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </EmailProvider>
  );
};

export default EmailIDPage;

My Questions:

Is this approach (moving context and data fetching to each page) efficient, or is there a better way to handle this?
Is there a recommended pattern for handling dynamic routes and context in Next.js 14, given that useParams isn't available in layouts and layouts don’t re-render with dynamic route changes?
Would it be better to manage email state globally in a different way to avoid duplication across the pages?

Any guidance would be appreciated!
